# Nested SQL Query for count of months

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and would like to know how to approach writing a query for this question.
Lets say we have these fields:
date_created  date_unsubscribed  subscriberid

[image]

How to write a SQL query that lists, by month, how many people subscribed to the list, unsubscribed from the list, and how many net subscribers there were (new subscribers minus unsubscribers).
All in a single query...

Comment: Is this MySql or Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation` and `union all`:

```
select month(dt), 
       count(case when subscribe = 1 then 1 end) subscribecount,
       count(case when subscribe = -1 then 1 end) unsubscribecountt,
       sum(subscribe) overallcount
from (
   select date_created as dt, 1 as subscribe
   from yourtable
   union all
   select date_unsubscribed, -1
   from yourtable
   where date_unsubscribed is not null
) t
group by month(dt)
```

The subquery creates a list of dates with a flag for subscribe or unsubscribe.  Then you can use `count` with `case` to determine the appropriate number of subscribers/unsubscribers.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c01b63/5)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a sum(case) (a sum with conditions) to aggregate - assuming the date_created column is never null. For instance:

ORACLE:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(DATE_CREATED,'MM-YYYY') CREATE_MONTH
,SUM(CASE WHEN date_unsubscribed is not null then 1 else 0 end) unsubscribed
,SUM(CASE WHEN date_unsubscribed is null then 1 else 0 end) subscribed
,COUNT(SUBSCRIBER_ID)
FROM
--YOURTABLENAME
--WHERE
--WHATEVER OTHER CONDITIONS YOU HAVE APPLY
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_CREATED,'MM-YYYY')
```

MYSQL:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_CREATED,'%m-%Y') CREATE_MONTH
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN date_unsubscribed is not null then 1 else 0 end) unsubscribed
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN date_unsubscribed is null then 1 else 0 end) subscribed
    ,COUNT(SUBSCRIBER_ID)
    FROM
    --YOURTABLENAME
    --WHERE
    --WHATEVER OTHER CONDITIONS YOU HAVE APPLY
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE_CREATED,'%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle solution**

Here is a query using the PIVOT operator, which was created exactly for this kind of work, and ROLLUP to get the net number. This is just for illustration; I assume the year is a user or application input (bind variable `:year`, set to 2015 for the output), and I show the summary for January through June.

```
with
     test_data ( date_created, date_unsubscribed, subscriber_id ) as (
       select date '2015-05-10', null             , 330053448 from dual union all
       select date '2015-04-28', null             , 330053457 from dual union all
       select date '2015-05-10', null             , 330053466 from dual union all
       select date '2015-04-28', null             , 220053475 from dual union all
       select date '2015-04-28', date '2015-05-10', 330053484 from dual
     ),
     prep ( type, val, mth ) as (
       select  'Subscribed'  ,  1, extract(month from date_created)      from test_data
          where extract(year from date_created)      = :year
       union all
       select  'Unsubscribed', -1, extract(month from date_unsubscribed) from test_data
          where extract(year from date_unsubscribed) = :year
     ) 
select nvl(type, 'Net Subscr') as description,
       nvl(sum(jan), 0) as jan, nvl(sum(feb), 0) as feb, nvl(sum(mar), 0) as mar, 
       nvl(sum(apr), 0) as apr, nvl(sum(may), 0) as may, nvl(sum(jun), 0) as jun
from prep
pivot (
         sum(val)
         for mth in (1 as jan, 2 as feb, 3 as mar, 4 as apr, 5 as may, 6 as jun)
      )
group by rollup(type)
order by case type when 'Subscribed' then 1 when 'Unsubscribed' then 2 else 3 end
;


DESCRIPTION         JAN        FEB        MAR        APR        MAY        JUN
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Subscribed            0          0          0          3          2          0
Unsubscribed          0          0          0          0         -1          0
Net Subscr            0          0          0          3          1          0

3 rows selected.
```